# Determining the Transfer Function of a Wheatstone Bridge

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, wheatstone-bridge

I am designing a Wheatstone Bridge, and would like to calculate the transfer function of the bridge input to the bridge output.

The Wheatstone Bridge is designed as follows: 
[image: Wheatstone Bridge]

Three of the resistors are identical, with the fourth being a potentiometer.

In this case the bridge input is 5V, but I'm not sure how to relate this to the bridge output.

UPDATE:  There are two voltage dividers, where:

\$V_- = 5V(potentiometer/ (potentiometer + R1))\$

\$V_+ = 5V(R1/ (R1+ R1)) = 5/2\$

Comment: These are two voltage dividers. V- = 5V (POT/(R1+POT)). The second is left as an exercise.

Comment: @Mario so the second would be: \$V_+ = 5V(R1/ (R1+ R1)) = 5/R1\$

Comment: R1/(R1+R1) =1/2

Comment: Now we could define Vout as Vout = V+ - V- = ... and that's it.

Comment: @Mario of course! My mistake.  So then \$V_o = 5V(potentiometer/ (potentiometer + R1)) - (5/2)\$

Comment: @Mario so then the function would simply be (5/Vo)?

Comment: No, the function is the equation you've just derived.

Comment: ... Typically a transfer function is \${V_O \over V_{IN}}\$, but in your case the input is a potentiometer position. So this transfer function would be in terms of \${V_O \over R_{IN}}\$.

Comment: Or if it is some angular measurement, you can sub the angle-to-resistance function in and get in terms of \${V_O \over \alpha_{IN}}\$.

Comment: Wait... is the bridge input 5V? Or the potentiometer? Which one is fixed and which one moves?

Comment: @Daniel The bridge input is 5v! The potentiometer moves

Comment: @tibsar That means that the potentiometer position is the bridge input, does it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tansfer functions are written Vout/Vin, so in your case
V-/Vin = pot/(pot+R1)
V+/Vin = R1/(R1+R1) = 1/2

Usually the outputs of a Wheatstone Bridge are put into an instrumentation or differential amplifier. Then the transfer function will change to something like the following:

tf_inst_amp = (V+/Vin - V-/Vin) * gain_of_diff_amp = (V+-V-)*gain_of_diff_amp/Vin

Comment: Transfer functions are typically Vo/Vin.

Comment: whoops nice catch